# vba excel list to word with chapters

Tags: excel, select, duplicates, vba

**From this:**
[image: excel data]

I would like to move and style the content in

**Word as this :**
[image: Word document]

using VBA.

I succeeded in identify the "component" duplicates to use this as chapters names in Word. But now, for me the hard part is to select "spare parts" only related to concerned "component", copy them and paste them. I know how to open Word, create a Word document, and paste into it. But I'm just blocked in selecting the right thing to be pasted.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will load data from Excel into 2D array. First the dimensions of the array are determined, than the data is saved into the array. New Word document is created and data from array is saved to Word file. Every first item from the array is saved as new paragraph, other data is saved in the table. No Word formating is done.

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit
Sub TwoD_Tbl_to_Word()
    Dim MyArr() As String
    Dim comidx As Long
    Dim partidx As Long
    Dim partidxtmp As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim teststr As String

    Dim objWd As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim myRange As Word.Range

    teststr = Cells(5, 2)
    comidx = 1
    partidx = 1
    partidxtmp = 1

'detect 2D Array Indexes
    For i = 6 To ActiveSheet.Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If Cells(i, 2) = teststr Then
            partidxtmp = partidxtmp + 1
        Else
        teststr = Cells(i, 2)
        If partidxtmp > partidx Then
            partidx = partidxtmp
        End If
        partidxtmp = 1
        comidx = comidx + 1
        End If
    Next i

'if the last item is the biggest
    If partidxtmp > partidx Then
        partidx = partidxtmp
    End If
'redefine array
    ReDim MyArr(comidx, partidx + 1)

'load Excel into Array
    teststr = Cells(5, 2)
    MyArr(1, 1) = Cells(5, 2)
    MyArr(1, 2) = Cells(5, 3)
    partidxtmp = 2
    comidx = 1

    For i = 6 To ActiveSheet.Columns("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        If Cells(i, 2) = teststr Then
           partidxtmp = partidxtmp + 1
           MyArr(comidx, partidxtmp) = Cells(i, 3)
        Else
           comidx = comidx + 1
           teststr = Cells(i, 2)
           MyArr(comidx, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
           MyArr(comidx, 2) = Cells(i, 3)
           partidxtmp = 2
        End If
    Next i
'Create Word
    Set objWd = CreateObject("word.application")
    objWd.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWd.Documents.Add

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyArr, 1)
        objWd.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        objWd.Selection.TypeText Text:=i & ". " & MyArr(i, 1)
        objWd.Selection.TypeParagraph
        Set myRange = objWd.Selection.Range
        partidx = 1
'number of rows in Word table
        For partidxtmp = 2 To UBound(MyArr, 2)
            If Not MyArr(i, partidxtmp) = vbNullString Then
                partidx = partidx + 1
            End If
        Next partidxtmp

        objDoc.Tables.Add Range:=myRange, NumRows:=partidx - 1, NumColumns:=1

        For partidxtmp = 1 To partidx - 1
            objDoc.Tables(i).Cell(partidxtmp, 1).Range.Text = MyArr(i, partidxtmp + 1)
        Next partidxtmp

        Set myRange = objDoc.Tables(i).Range
        myRange.EndOf wdStory, wdMove
        myRange.InsertAfter vbCr
    Next i

    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @macejd,

Your detailed code was very helpful and gave me ways to get what I wanted.
More precisely, thanks to you I spotted some new things and errors from me in VB :
- declare Range for my Word tables in the For loops,
- Use objDoc and not objWd to insert tables,
- search more info and learn about 2D arrays (I used to use 1D arrays). For this, Wise Owl's Youtube channel is a gold mine
- detect empty array items with vbNullString.

I didn't know I would get an answer so fast. Thanks again.